# Force user to enter credentials everytime Facebook iOS application

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using facebook sdk (4.4) in ios application for "SignIn with facebook" and "Sharing photos" features. As "Sharing photos" must require facebook application installed in user's iphone. So we used the same approach for "SignIn with facebook" feature as well.

So ios app uses facebook native app for sharing and "SignIn with facebook". Now i want to force user to enter credentials every time when "SignIn with facebook" button is clicked. It will redirect user to facebook native app and if user is already logged in, it will automatically redirect to ios app. Is that possible to clear session (logout) from facebook native app programatically ?

Comment: It is already basic functionality of iOS facebook signIn, when the user is already logged in, it does not ask username and password. What is your requirement, can you further explain it.

Comment: my client wants such feature to force user every time enter username and password whenever fb signin button pressed.

Comment: I do not think that's possible. You can only invalidate your own session. That will require user to click "SignIn with Facebook" button every time. But, if (s)he is logged in to Facebook iOS app, then your app would simply authorize that user.

Comment: Have you looked at Facebook's reauthentication flow? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication 
It's not supported in the Facebook SDK for Android or iOS, but if this is a hard requirement you may be able to set up some sort of web based verification